# How to load pictures from a USB drive into a localhost html page

Tags: usb

So I'm trying to setup a display using this [shifting tiles animation](http://hermanbanken.github.io/shiftingtiles/). I'm not putting it on a website, it's just going to be used on the local raspberry pi to display on a TV (http://localhost/) so I'm not worried about security. I've got it working by adding a few photos into the /var/www/html/ directory. But I'd like to be able to fill up a large flashdrive with 1000's of photos and randomly pull from that. My problem is I can't seem to get the permissions to do so. Are there any simple ways to read files from a usb drive?

Comment: what happens if you add a link to the USB drive into the /var/www/html/ directory?

Comment: @Michael, to add a link, do something like this: `ln path/to/target linkName`. You could do this for each picture, or add a link directly to the folder containing all the pictures.

Comment: well I think my issues are with permissions. Won't the link not work if www-data doesn't have permission to read/write on the USB?

Answer (score 1):

Try 'sudo' to copy or link the files as 'root' to bypass permissions.

e.g.

`sudo ln -s /[flashdrive-path]/*.jpg /var/www/html/`

A neater way may be with relative path links, e.g. something like

`sudo sh -c 'cd /var/www/html; ln -s /[flashdrive-path]/*.jpg .'`

You could then change ownership to www-data using 'sudo chown on the symlinks'

If you still have permission problems, and you're not worried about security, you could make the image files and sub-directories readable by all, e.g.

`chmod -R a+r /[flashdrive-path]/*`